# Flask-Admin Role based resource permissions

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-admin, flask-security, flask-principal

I am creating a Flask-Admin app that requires checking permissions to View, Edit & Delete certain rows in a table.

i.e, I would like to:

- List only rows where the User ID matches the Owner ID of the row
- Let the user Create a row if they have a certain Role
- Only let user Edit a row if they have a certain Role

I can think of overriding methods query(), on_model_change(), etc to check an Edit permit, but:

- A user could still view the row by changing the URL to display the Edit screen
- I don't know how to restrict a WTForms one-to-many edit list to only allowed items

How may I achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen the [**Flask-RBAC**](https://flask-rbac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) extension which gives a role based access control?

Comment: I didn't know Flask-RBAC, but I don't see how it gives any advantage over Flask-Security or Flask-Principal in solving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty solution to my own problem:

**1.** Create a generic function to check ownership in the ModelView class

```
def is_owned(self, id):
    model = db.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.id == id).all()
    if len(model) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        model = model[0]
    if model.user_id == current_user.id:
        return True
    return False
```

**2.** Override ModelView's on_model_change, on_form_prefill, on_model_delete, get_query and get_count_query methods to check for ownership (user_id = current_user.id):

```
def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
    if not self.is_owned(model.id):
        abort(403)

def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
    if not self.is_owned(id):
        abort(403)

def on_model_delete(self, model):
    if not self.is_owned(model.id):
        abort(403)

def get_query(self):
    return super(Tables, self).get_query().filter(self.model.user_id == current_user.id)

def get_count_query(self):
    return super(Tables,self).get_count_query().filter(self.model.user_id == current_user.id)
```